# php with oracle on IIS 

Tags: php, oracle, iis, windows-xp, iis-5

yep, it sounds like an unholy alliance but I need to configure how to do it...
for starters I have on my PC installed Oracles PL/SQL environment, with latest client (11g, I think) ... I can work in theirs IDE w/o any problems. I even can code desktop apps with C# and Oracle connector (etc.)

Now, from MS site I can click on that Web Installer thing, and it installs PHP for my IIS - the default on which runs on WinXP ... And id works... (coded the famous "Hello World" app).

Next step is the connection to Oracle... I've read many tutorials on the web - and they suggest me uncommenting lines in php.ini with "php_oci8.dll" - but I never saw those lines (not commented and not uncommented - just nothing), there's no such file in "ext" folder - either. I have found 'em and added them there myself - no change (restarted the server too).

frustrated...

Comment: If you are "setting this up" it suggests you don't have any dependencies yet... if so, why are your going for such an odd stack? e.g. why not Apache? Do you need Oracle or would PostgreSQL work too?

Comment: If I could I'll chose sth like php+apache+mysql, but... We use Oracle db, I can't install Apache for various reasons, and php is - because later I'll switch to Apache - but not until I'll show _the benefits_

Comment: I'd start with the Oracle / PHP manual. There's a section on setting up PHP on Windows. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got that kind of configuration in our server, and I'm having correct lines in php.ini file. So I suggest to reinstall PHP with original PHP installation package http://php.net/downloads.php. There are php.ini-dist and php.ini-recommended files.

Comment: I have installed from there and not from MS site, configured fastcgi myself and everything worked. lesson: not to download from MS site if you want oracle :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at Zend Server / Zend Server CE as it includes the latest Zend Oracle library which is **much** better than the oci8 one.

The Windows installer is also very easy to use and it should configure IIS for you.